# Why my render result is different from render preview (not the camera lock kind of problem)

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera

[image]

I'm new in blender. I find my render result is different from the the preview. I've locked the camera angle so it's not a camera lock problem.

It happens when I do the scale with geometry node or with a mesh deform modifier. But I've chose to apply all the transformation but the problem always there.
I don't know what's the problem.

Here is the link of the blend file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nDxS0LY4FkU3jRSPkhFeCffVXX4KF4FN/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: Thanks Chris. I've update a link of the blend file. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it could be two things. Or you have another camera selecten in your scene propperties, or you have VR mode checked in sterioscopy. It will render two eye positions that way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I've checked there is no another camera and I haven't used a VR mode. :(